# simple html / css header

Tags: html, css

So, i am doing a webpage for my youtube channel, and to grow my portfolio, and i have seem to become stuck. This is the comparison to the two [image]
Left is what i have, Right is what i want. 
I cant really attach the code as i have used absolute links. 
I've tried playing with the margins but the image wont move, and i do not know how to make it to the image is the center, and the text is evenly spread apart. I'm new to all this, hence why i can't do it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regardless whether you're using absolute links or not some code would let us know how exactly you're doing everything.  I'm sure if you post the header code and the css code and just remove the links we'd still be able to better understand how you're trying to center the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out ....http://jsfiddle.net/ypg1d93a/1/

```
<div id="header">
        <div  class="menu">
            <p>Menu1</p>
        </div>
        <div  class="menu">
            <p>Menu2</p>
        </div>
        <div  class="menu">
            <img src="https://skypeblogs.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/skype-logo-feb_2012_rgb_500.png" >
        </div>
        <div  class="menu">
             <p>Menu3</p>
        </div>
        <div  class="menu">
             <p>Menu4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and css

```
        *
        {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }

        .menu
        {
            height:40px;
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            text-align:center;
        }
        .menu p{
            line-height:40px;
        }
        .menu img
        {
            max-width:100px;
            height:40px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all of the links the same left/right margin, then give the image a slight left/right margin. When you have done that you need to find with of the header and set it with `width:`. You can then add `margin: 0 auto;` to the header to centre it.

I can't give you much more without the code you are using. The information above is also not mobile friendly. You will need to add dropdown menus when the screen is too small to achieve a mobile friendly site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so

```css
body {
    background: url('http://extrawallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Wave-Nature-hd-Wallpaper.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
}
nav {}
nav > ul {          
    text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav > ul > li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin: 0 3px;    
    font-family: sans-serif;    
    border: 2px solid transparent;    
}
nav > ul > li a:hover {
    border: 2px solid #fff;    
}

.logo{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```